# Suggestion on treeview control that renders valid xhtml and works withou javascript

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for an ASP.NET control that renders a tree structure, very much like the ASP.NET TreeView control, but filling the following requirements:

- Dont uses tables for rendering tree structure.
- Markup Adhering to valid XHTML 1.0 Strict.
- Works with AND without javascript.

Also, if the control is licensed under a MIT och GPL licens that would be great, but commercial controls is also of interest.

Do anyone know of any such control? If not, well, then I'll simply have to write the control myself. More fun in my own opinion, but likely more time consuming.

Thanx!

Comment: I have no idea how asp controls work, but I think you can simply generate a nested unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try Telerik RadTreeView
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/treeview.aspx

it's a commercial control.

Comment: ...and the markup it emits is awful, and has a dependency on Javascript too, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd continue to use the standard ASP.NET Treeview control, but apply a control adapter ([see here](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/treeview.aspx)) to make the mark-up it emits more acceptable.